# Powershell - Hex to IEEE754 Single-Precision Floating-Point

Tags: powershell, floating-point, hex

I'm new in Powershell and I'm struggling with a basic conversion from hex to float.

I'd like to convert 0x46FEEBD0 to float number 32629.90625 (IEEE754 standard).
All my attempts gave me 1191111632 (or 1,191112E+09) which is the decimal representation of 0x46FEEBD0.

Is there a simple Powershell method to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [BitConverter.ToSingle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
# Get the byte representation (produces D0, EB, FE, 46)
$bytes = [BitConverter]::GetBytes([single]32629.90625)
$bytes | Foreach-Object { ("{0:X2}" -f $_) }

# Convert the $bytes back to a float (produces 32629.91)
[BitConverter]::ToSingle($bytes, 0)
```

**Edit**: Thanks to LotPings for pointing out that I should be using single rather than double.

Comment: Put `[single]` in front of 32629.90625

Comment: And change second line to `($bytes[$Bytes.Length..0] | Foreach-Object { ("{0:X2}" -f $_) }) -join("")`